# Sloppy DC pre-filtering for 24V → 5V 1A Buck converter

Tags: buck

I have done DC converters before, both the curious way (AVRing it) and the lazy engineer's way (applying a datasheet formula) but it was always from nice DC sources with a fairly big filter cap.

Now, just for the reason of **size**, I'd like to go with a much smaller filter cap on the input, so the DC will have much ripple on it. I imagine this is going to muddle common buck-converter designs.

I'm looking for advice from people who did such a stunt before. What to look for to select a buck converter chip which behaves tame in such a situation?

EDIT: I found it's worth to note, these are many tiny boards needing +5V, and supplied 24VAC from a central distribution.

Comment: To lower C, you must consider raising f.

Comment: I thought about that, Tony, but my flawed thinking lead me into the completely different direction. Could you please elaborate it in an answer?

Comment: Perhaps you should list all acceptance criteria and assumptions for source impedance

Comment: Uh, I wasn't prepared for that.

Comment: Who said even with no input cap it will be such a mess? Is it based on something or just a guess?

Comment: *I imagine* == just a guess. Sorry not being clearer on this, but certainly I could just *try it*, then fall into a pit because it only works so-so. Oh, yes, and it could also boil down to shopping advice, I know. I just need some pointers what to avoid. Tony's direction to high frequencies helped already.

Comment: The switching frequency doesn't necessarily mean that your control loop will have higher bandwidth. And not sure this is what you would need. My guess is that y don't have to worry at all.

Comment: Yeah, you are probably right. I could also dive into theory again (last time I did this was ~20 years ago) but I'm a bit wary, that's why I'm after practical advice.

Comment: This is exactly what I've been working on lately, and I highly recommend a bit of experimentation.  What I discovered is in line with what Tony says.  Increasing frequency in pwm seems to allow physically smaller input caps and also smaller output caps and inductors.  You can calculate the total charge output of your maximum PWM signal (1A=1 coulomb/sec) in coulombs and think of that as a packet size.  The capacitor has to compensate for one packet at a time, so as the frequency increases, the charge in the packet decreases.

Comment: If lowering the capacitor causes more ripple, then where does the ripple come from - is it the output from a bridge rectifier? Is it the cable inductance connecting a steady DC voltage to the buck converter?

Comment: @K H, thanks for the input. I was already thinking I had to experiment, just need some pointers and consolidation the chosen path is correct.

Comment: @Andy aka, it's straight from a bridge rectifier. Hmmm, I should have written 33V then. And no, cable inductance on the 24VAC side may vary but should be too low in general. On DC, it's one centimeter of track. As this is crucial information, I edit the question.

Comment: @Janka do you have a buck regulator in mind?

Comment: Yes. I could also go with a pre-regulator, then another regulator for reaching +5V. To me, most important is the whole thing must be flat and fitting on 4x6cm board space with no/only a flat heatsink. I also thought about an array of input filter caps but I would happily leave them out if there's no problem with that.